# C# list inheritance

Tags: c#, list, inheritance

I'm writing a C# program that deals with songs. I have a Song class and a SongCollection class that inherits a list of type Song. I need to write a method that takes an artist (string) as its parameter and I need to return a new SongCollection of that artist. I'm having some difficulty accessing the list of songs.

```
public SongCollection GetAllByArtist(string artist)
{
        SongCollection newSongs = new SongCollection();
        if (this.Artist == artist)
        {
            newSongs.Add(this.Song);
        }
        return newSongs;
}
```

Comment: Where is this method? (what is `this`?)

Answer (score 5):

This should work for you:

```
 public SongCollection GetAllByArtist(string artist)
 {
    SongCollection newSongs = new SongCollection();
    newSongs.AddRange(this.Where(p=>p.Artist == artist))        
    return newSongs;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the collection and do your artist check on each song, not on the list itself:

```
public SongCollection GetAllByArtist(string artist)
{
        SongCollection newSongs = new SongCollection();
        foreach (Song s in this) {
            if (s.Artist == artist)
            {
                newSongs.Add(s);
            }
        }
        return newSongs;
}
```

Comment: NOTE: This assumes that the class SongCollection implements an iterator exposing the internal collection of Song objects. (Not saying it is wrong, just making note)

Comment: I interpreted the OP's description ("a SongCollection class that inherits a list of type Song") as a statement that his class inherits List<Song>.